# Pycharm identifies new Django test file as a unittest, not a django test

Tags: django, pycharm

How do I tell pycharm that the new test file I created is a django test file, and not a unittest file?

I have pycharm setup with a django project. I can run all django tests as django tests with the test runner.

I created a new test file, wrote a simple unittest on it. The tests run fine with `manage.py` and with the run configuration for running all tests.

But, when I try to run an individual test within the new test file from pycharm it fails because pycharm is trying to run it as a `unittest` instead of a django test. As shown in the screenshots below, pycharm considers this new file a unittest file, not a django test file. Yet both files are in the same directory (`tests`), both implement a class that extends `Unittest`, and both have tests.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have the box below unchecked which is, not wrong?

[image]

Comment: I usually do this: `Run > Edit Configurations` to open the `Edit Run/Debug configuration` dialog. Then, click on `+` button and select `Django test`.

Comment: Yeah. I setup a "Django Tests" Run Configuration that runs all the tests in my new test file. That is my current workaround. Still, I would like to be able to run individual tests in that file by clicking on the green arrow next to each one (I will have many), just like in my old file. Mostly I just want to know why pycharm recognizes one test.py file as Django Test but the other one as UnitTest, and how do I make pycharm recognize that file should be a Django Test file.

Comment: In Preferences, Languages & Frameworks, Django, what's the checkbox "Do not use Django Test runner"?

Comment: It is unchecked. Added screenshot above.

Answer (score 3):

After a good night's sleep the solution became obvious.

The new `testfile.py` had

```py
from unittest import TestCase
```

I changed that to

```py
from django.test import TestCase
```

and now pycharm recognizes it as a python test file.